go mod returns 404 while curl returns 200 OK or how to debug go mod
I have a problem that may seems trivial, but I spend hours solving it and nothing helps.
First of all, I cannot reproduce it anywhere but on my machine.
For some reason go mod  gets 404 instead of 200 when it tries to receive metadata about a module.
$ go mod download -x gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2@latest
# get https://gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2?go-get=1
# get https://gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.256s)

If I run curl in the same bash session, I got plain 200 OK
$ curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n"  https://gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2?go-get=1
200

Do you have any ideas on how to debug such thing? -x doesn't help much
I tried reproducing this problem on another machine and I cannot reproduce it. Even with this very same machine when I run a docker image, go mod gets 200 OK
$ go mod download -x  gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2@latest
# get https://proxy.golang.org/gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2/@v/list
# get https://proxy.golang.org/gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2/@v/list: 404 Not Found (2.142s)
# get https://gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2?go-get=1
# get https://gitlab.com/secret/secret-repo/v2?go-get=1: 200 OK (0.215s)

I just don't know how to debug go mod further. Also, it ignores http_proxy or HTTP_PROXY variables, so I don't know how to proerly make it work with mitmproxy for example.
Other things that I've tried: trying the same command for another user, and it works returning 200 OK.
When I login into my user shell, even with non envasive su myuser -s /bin/sh having almost identical env, it still returns 404. I just don't know how to debug it further.

You don't notice anything special when running go env command ?

It looks you have some invalid HTTP credentials in your $HOME/.netrc, so when you go mod download your private module, the go command authenticates with those credentials giving you a 404. On the other side, curl doesn't use your .netrc credentials by default (and the other environment you tested and the Docker build don't have access to your .netrc), so you get a 200 response there.

You are right, but tell me please, how did you come to this conclusion? Have you run into similar issues previously? I spent hours before I found the reason.

The 404 usually arises with an invalid auth when dealing with private repos, and given the curl worked fine, it could only be the .netrc file adding some credentials. The problem is go mod download -x doesn't show anything about credentials for security reasons.


"doesn't show anything about credentials for security reasons"

It totally could show the fact that it loaded some credentials from .netrc, it wouldn't hurt in terms of security at all.
